# Ternary logic in XPath for testing null

Tags: sharepoint, xpath, infopath, logical-operators

In XPath 1.0, is there a way to test the existence of the evaluated expression and modify the result on its behalf?

I am trying to implement this pseudo-code:

```
if ID is empty
     then 0 + 1
     else ID + 1
```

Actual code, so far:

```
xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Max(
    xdXDocument:GetDOM("FetchID")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataField‌​s/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:ID),
    'concat("(ID = ", (d:ID or 0) + 1,")")'
)
```

This expression doesn't work when there is no item in the list, hence `max(d:ID)` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's usually an ugly workaround, something like

```
concat("0", ID) + 1
```